# Javascript Vue 3 - Cannot upload image to Firebase Storage after create new authentication account to Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3, firebase-storage

I tried to make a simple registration form where admin able to create new user including photo profile of the new user, but it return an error when trying upload the image after the authentication created(user already created in Firebase Authentication)

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'files')

```
const photo = ref(null)

const formData = reactive({
    fn: "",
    ln: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
})

const signUp = async () => {
    const result = await v$.value.$validate()
    if(result){
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, formData.email, formData.password)
        .then(function(data) {
            const imagesRef = stRef(storage, 'images/'+data.user.uid)
            uploadBytes(imagesRef, photo.value.files[0]).then((snapshot) => {
                console.log(photo.value.files[0]);
            })
            setDoc(doc(db, "users", data.user.uid), {
                fn : formData.fn,
                ln : formData.ln,
                uid: data.user.uid,
                email: formData.email,
            })
            closeModal()
            router.go()
            alert("Success, form submitted.")
        })
    .catch(error => {
        switch (error.code) {
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
                errMsg.value = 'Invalid email address or password';
                break;
            case 'auth/user-not-found':
                errMsg.value = 'User not found';
                break;
            case 'auth/wrong-password':
                errMsg.value = 'Invalid email address or password';
                break;
            case 'auth/internal-error':
                errMsg.value = 'Invalid email address or password';
                break;
            case 'auth/missing-email':
                errMsg.value = 'Fill email address or password field';
                break;
            case 'auth/email-already-in-use': 
                errMsg.value = 'Email already used';
                break;
            default:
                errMsg.value = error.message;
                break;
        }
    });
    } else {
        alert(errMsg.value, "Form failed to submitted")
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you update the `photo` ref value in this code (which you declared as `ref(null)`, so the error is caused because `photo.value` is null on the line:

```
uploadBytes(imagesRef, photo.value.files[0])
```

Not sure what `photo.value` is supposed to be, but you need to make sure to assign something to it before accessing it in the `signUp` function.

Comment: but I want to save the image filename using newly created user UID, how do I achieve this? it run perfectly if I just directly save image to storage with original image filename without auth function first.